# Road bike shipped with one of the brake cable heads disconnected from the brake lever

Tags: road-bike, brakes, cable, new-bicycle-assembly, drop-bar

[image][image]Is there an easy fix for this?  From what I can see, looks like I have to remove the handlebar tape, and route the cable from the handle bar through the casing etc like new.  I got the bike from the "direct" "bikes" store.  Did not expect this.  One of the brakes is working and the other has this issue and no action.

Comment: Can you specify the exact bike model and also post some pictures?

Comment: We definitely need a photo please.  
Was it poorly assembled, or has the brake cable pulled through the brake lever?   If its the first, you need the whole thing quality checked by someone who can build bikes.  If its the latter, I'd return it for a complete refund based on an utter lack of confidence in their ability to make a safe bike.

Comment: Photos please so we don't misunderstand. It is very unusual for the cable to have not been inserted in the first place, I can't see how - but if it is this problem then it raises serious questions. But it seems much less possible for the cable head to pull through the shifter and housing. If the head is just poking back out of the lever, perhaps a section of housing has just come loose down the line and needs reseating.

Comment: Depends on the design of the lever and cable layout, but if you can somehow gain enough slack in the cable you often can kind of kink it so that it will feed through slots in the lever and engage the circular hole where the head should reside.  Likely it was built properly assembled, but when the handlebar was twisted around for shipping this knocked the cable out.

Comment: The bike is a Gravity D Roadbike.  It was shipped in a box and this company says it is 80 to 90% assembled.  All I had to do was fix the front wheel, handlebar, seat posts and the pedals.

Comment: It looks like you just need to reach in there and pop the ferrule back into place. There's a cradle underneath it that the two white ends of the ferrule fit into.

Comment: @NoahSutherland,  The ferrule wasn't disconnected,  The head was not in the ferrule slot.  I had to pull the cable out and route it back in through the ferrule slot.

Comment: Great work!  That looks like piss-poor assembly on their part.  You should check over your bike thoroughly to be sure nothing else is messed up, just to be sure.

Comment: @randomnamedude sorry, I guess I'm not seeing it clearly in your photos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd recommend a new inner cable from the shop.

That is your brake that you are playing with and how important is it that they work when you use them?

There will be a you tube video on line on how to replace an inner cable, and it's not too difficult, as it's a normal service procedure

Comment: You'll be able to pick up a new cable for cheap from a bike store for cheap if they are still open where you live

Answer (score 2):

You probably won't need to unwrap the bar tape - simply release the inner wire from the pinch nut/bolt on the brake, possibly pull off any end cap crimp, and pull the wire all the way up and out.

Retwist any loose strands of brake cable so it lies flat.  I suggest you use a drop of superglue now on the very end to keep it all together.  When set, carry on.

Then squeeze that brake lever, peer down the hole and feed the glued end through the brake's stop, and then into the inner cable.  It may go easy, it may take a very long time to get it in the hole you can't see... there is no guarantee that the holes line up.

One trick is to use another length of brake cable, and feed it up from below temporarily.  Then when you see it come up into the brake lever, use that end to guide the proper brake cable into the unseen outer.

---

If you can't get it within 10 minutes, give up and unwrap the bartape on that side.  It should unwrap from the middle so its not too bad.  You'll probably need some tape to close it up again when done.   It may help to very-slightly dirty the bar tape before unwrapping, so you can see where they overlapped.  Perhaps a pencil dragged across the underside of the bars where it can't be seen.

When you do get the wire through, remember to seat it in the brake's pinch bolt, and adjust the brake as required.  And test before riding.

Good luck!

Comment: If the cable is removed one might as well install a new one, as fiddling withe the existing one, with it's frayed end, will be difficult.

Comment: @Daniel makes a good point, though the super glue trick works well, just a tiny dab

Comment: @Swifty I've also used solder and flux in the past, but only works on clean new cables where one strand keeps getting away during install.